# jQuery not inserting attribute into the link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a link to slide down a div as follows.But initially this link has no `onclick` handler, which I am inserting using the jQuery code.

```
<a href="#" id="Link_1">Show Div</a>
```

Now the following is the jquery code

```
  //id comes from a loop which runs from 1 to 15

$("#Link_"+id).attr('onclick','$(\'#Div_'+id+'\').slideToggle(\'slow\');');
$("#Link_"+id).attr('style','color:white;');
$("#Link_"+id).attr('value','0');
```

The last two lines are inserting attributes but the first line is not working and also I am not getting any error.I am using jQuery 1.4

**EDIT**

Now the surprise,I just by luck tried it,
the first line is working in jquery 1.9.Why?

Comment: what are you trying to bind ??

Comment: will u put it in jsfiddle & share us the link?

Comment: Setting `onclick` attribute with jQuery? That's insane.

Comment: @undefined:Hmmm,in that case it justifies my name as well.

Comment: Using event attributes is a _bad practice_. You are loading jQuery, use it's methods, if something should happen based on an specific condition you can _handle_ it in you event _handler_. Also I'm sure that you don't need that loop at all. There are better ways for selecting the target elements.

Answer (score 4):

You can't add a click handler like that, try this instead:

```
$("#Link_"+id).live('click', function(){
    $('#Div_'+id+'').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Comment: Read the question properly.I do not want to call click handler,The task is that initially the link is disabled(missing handler and color gray).After a particular event I am calling those three lines so that color changes to white and the link now has a handler also

Comment: It's not **calling** the click handler; it's **adding** a click handler. See jQuery [on](http://api.jquery.com/live/) documentation.

Comment: This will do what you want if it is wrapped in the function that is triggered on whatever event you are talking about. But needs to be live not on for jquery 1.4

Comment: Why `live` and not `click`?

Answer (score 0):

Try binding it this way:

```
$("#Link_"+id).on("click", function () { 
  $('#Div_'+id+).slideToggle('slow');
});
```

as you are using jquery 1.4. You would be needing `live` instead of `on`

```
$("#Link_"+id).live( "click", function() {
 $('#Div_'+id+).slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `.click()` instead.

```
$("#Link_"+id).click(function(){
    $('#Div_'+id).slideToggle('slow');
    return false;
});
```

To answer the edit: jQuery 1.9 checks if you are trying to set an event handler and adds the handler instead of setting an attribute. jQuery 1.4 doesn't have such a check. (I looked at the source)